# Does Android support .dat extension file?

Tags: android

Actually i just want to know that whether Android Mobile phones support " .dat " file extensions. I want to save a dynamic graph in " .dat " extension format.

Please go through the below video link

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=td75nzaCrX8

In this link someone has saved the graph in " .dat " extension.

Please help me guys. Best wishes and thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is the list of supported files :-http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 2):

> Actually i just want to know that whether Android Mobile phones support " .dat " file extensions.

Only if the users have installed an app that knows what a `.dat` file is and knows what a "dynamic graph" is. Out of the hundreds of millions of Android devices in use today, approximately 0% will have such an app installed. Either *your* app should handle `.dat` or you will need to recommend to your users other app(s) they could install to handle `.dat`.

Answer (score -1):

It is simple, follow the steps:

1. install mx player
2. rename extention to .flv
3. change settings to s/w decoder in mx player.
4. refresh the video list in mx player.
5. enjoy your video.

(I have tested on my arm v 7 device)